# Grails and Selenium: how to integrate the two?

Tags: selenium, groovy, grails-2.0

I'm looking to automate the testing of the UI part of my Grails project using Selenium. A number of options seem to exist:

- [Grails Selenium plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/selenium): doesn't appear to support programmatic test definitions?
- [Grails Selenium-RC plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/selenium-rc): links on the plugin page are broken, the only [Github repo](https://github.com/pivotal/selenium-rc) I can find appears to be the Ruby version...
- [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/) (and the [Grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/geb)), which hasn't made a 1.0 final release yet.

Can anyone recommend one of these tools in particular, or suggest a better way? Does any decent documentation exist describing how to test Grails applications with Selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have been using Geb + Geb Grails plugin (Selenium wrapper) in several projects for more then two years.

The release number might be < 1.0, but in stability (bugs & API) it can be considered + 1.0 quality IMHO.